# PhD application targeting only one professor

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, application

I hold a master degree. Currently, I'm preparing PhD applications for several universities in the USA and Canada. I already know quite well my research interests. At some universities, there is only one professor researching in this area. I would only state the name of this professor in my statement of purpose.

Is it recommandable to apply for a PhD at a university where only one professor is doing research in your desired field?

Comment: As an aside, after some 30 years post PhD, I still have many, many research interests. I say this because, frankly, I find it unlikely that you really know the full breadth of what research you would find interesting.

Comment: @JonCuster: I agree with you one solution would be to just broaden your research interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The important point to keep in mind for grad programs in the US is that you are applying to a *department* and not an *advisor.* By all means reach out to this professor to find out whether they are interested in taking you as a student, and if they are, then by all means mention that you "hope to work with XXX" in your application. But you need to make the case more generally why you're a good fit for the department and not just a good fit for a particular advisor.

Comment: As I commented in the post of Anonymous Physicist, it is unclear if it is a good practice to directly ask a professor before applying. However, it is very valuable to know that in the USA one applies to a departement and not a professor directly. In conclusion, in my opinion, the best way to solve this issue is to broaden the research interests to include 2-3 professors of a uni and mention them in the application.

Comment: @user148865 Maybe a few professors don't want to hear from any prospective students, but usually what they're trying to communicate is that no one professor has the power to "get you in." As I said, you're applying to a *department.*

Answer (score 4):

> Is it recommandable to apply for a PhD at a university where only one professor is doing research in your desired field?

- It is not the best idea since professors' personal lives, professional lives, and funding change frequently.  You can reduce your risk by having alternative supervisors in mind.
- If you do not want to waste your time applying for a position that does not exist, email the professor to ask if they are taking new students.

Comment: After a research within stackoverflow and the internet in general, I found out it is unclear if it's a good practice to directly ask a professor before applying, if s/he is willing to accept. Some professors explicitly state on their website that they don't want to get contacted in this context.

Comment: @user148865 1.  Send a customized email explaining why you are interested in the position.  2.  Do not ask if you will be accepted; ask if you should apply.